# Python Dataframe: Remove timestamp from calculated Days field

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, difference

I calculated a column using the following code:

```
df_EVENT5_5['age'] = dt.datetime.now().date() - df_EVENT5_5['dt_old']
    df_EVENT5_5['age_no_days'] = df_EVENT5_5['age'].dt.total_seconds()/ (24 * 60 * 60)
```

The output column contains the timestamp for some reason.

[image]

How do I remove the time stamp?

I tried below but didn't work:

```
remove_timestamp_col = ['COL_1', 'COL_2']

    for i in remove_timestamp_col:
        df_EVENT5_13[i] = df_EVENT5_13[i].age.days()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there might be some dates with time stamps in the data, try subtracting the date only:

```
df_EVENT5_5['age'] = dt.date.today() - df_EVENT5_5['dt_old'].apply(dt.datetime.date)
#This gives you the days difference as a number
df_EVENT5_5['age_no_days'] = df_EVENT5_5['age'].dt.days
#If you want it to have 'Days' in the end, you can use concatenation:
df_EVENT5_5['age_with_days'] = df_EVENT5_5['age_no_days'].astype('str') + ' Days'
```

Comment: When I write the table out to Excel I still see the time stamp in the cell value ..... help?

Comment: I have modified the code a bit, I have called the 'days' attribute instead of the 'total_seconds()' to give you the difference in days as a number, then you can concat it with the word 'days' to give the representation you want.

Comment: ah this is perfect!  I was missing the .dt.days code